# Visualizing large number of points as a 3D density map

Tags: visualization

The  result of my computational simulation is a (time-dependent) system of large number (~100k) of moving points in a confined space. Each point has its own Cartesian coordinates as well as a weight (w) in the form of $(x_i,y_i,z_i;w_i)$.

I'm looking for a software/app/package to create a snapshot of the 3D spatial density map of these points. ([something like this](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2013/130906/ncomms3414/fig_tab/ncomms3414_F3.html)).

[image]

Like you see in this figure, the points are not going to be displayed individually, but only a transparent cloud will be drawn whose local intensity is proportional with the local number of points.

The final goal is to create a movie of the changing 3D spatial density with time.

So far, I have tried R, Matlab, Origin, and ImageJ. But no success!

Comment: [One python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286811/how-to-plot-a-3d-density-map-in-python-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

In [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) you may use [`ListDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html).

First we create some data to plot using a 3D density function at three time points (0, .5, and 1) using [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

```
p[t_, x_, y_, z_] := Cos[t z] + x y
densityClouds = Table[{x, y, z, p[t, x, y, z]},
   {t, 0, 1, .5}, {x, -1, 1, .05}, {y, -1, 1, .05}, {z, π/2, 3 π/2, π/40}];
```

`densityClouds` contains the 3 clouds but it is not the correct format for `ListDensityPlot3D`.

```
Dimensions@densityClouds
```

> ```
> {3, 41, 41, 41, 4}
> ```

We can [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) the two upper layers of each cloud (the x and y coordinates) to the third layer (the z coordinate) to get the correct format.

```
densityClouds = Flatten[#, 2] & /@ densityClouds;
Dimensions@densityClouds
```

> ```
> {3, 68921, 4}
> ```

That we have data we can just plot the one of the clouds. The [`Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html) cloud is `t = 1`.

```
ListDensityPlot3D[Last@densityClouds,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

> [image]

You may find other list 3D plots in the [Data Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DataVisualization.html) guide useful (like [`ListContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot3D.html)) and their 3D equivalents in the [Function Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionVisualization.html) guide (like [`DensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot3D.html)).

Hope this helps.